# network analysis that includes user defined nodes

Tags: python, routing, analysis, nodes, network-analysis

I want to make network analysis using python. I want that user must be able to select point of interests and calculated route must contain that points.

For example between start and end nodes user, user want to visit 3 different location and calculated route must contain these locations, not just shortest path.

How can I make that? Any opinions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/)

> NetworkX is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

**Features**

- Data structures for graphs, digraphs, and multigraphs
- Many standard graph algorithms
- Network structure and analysis measures
- Generators for classic graphs, random graphs, and synthetic networks
- Nodes can be "anything" (e.g., text, images, XML records)
- Edges can hold arbitrary data (e.g., weights, time-series)
- Open source 3-clause BSD license
- Well tested with over 90% code coverage
- Additional benefits from Python include fast prototyping, easy to teach, and multi-platform